# generic definition of hibernate annotated classes

Tags: xml, hibernate, spring

following are my configuration of hibernate:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>              
                <value>${project.groupId}.domain.User</value>   
                <value>${project.groupId}.domain.Role</value>
                <value>${project.groupId}.domain.Permission</value>
                <value>${project.groupId}.domain.PermissionCategory</value>                         
            </list>

        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>

    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

i was wondering if it's possible to make **generic definition** of **annotated classes** instead of adding an entry for each class, something like:

```
<value>${project.groupId}.domain.*</value>
```

if anyone have an idea, please advise, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` supports the `packagesToScan` property as an alternative to `annotatedClasses`, so you should be able to do this:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="${project.groupId}.domain">
```